# From Latin prefixes and suffixes and its usage, does "absolute" denote "freedom" or "away from freedom"?

Tags: vocabulary, latin

First of all, I would like to apologize for my title's awkward formulation. English is not my mother-tongue.

I am looking at the word "absolute", which, according to [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/absolute?s=t), has the definition

> (4) free from restriction or limitation; not limited in any way: absolute command; absolute freedom.
>
> (5) unrestrained or unlimited by a constitution, counterbalancing group, etc., in the exercise of governmental power, especially when arbitrary or despotic: an absolute monarch.

and

> Origin:
> 1350–1400; Middle English  < Latin absolūtus  free, unrestricted, unconditioned (past participle of absolvere  to absolve), equivalent to *ab-* ab- + *solū-*  loosen + -tus  past participle suffix

I understand that the Latin prefix ***abs-*** means "away from" or "opposite to". However, when ***abs-*** is combined with ***solū***, or "loosen", the meaning seems to become "away from being loose" or "restricted" -- the opposite of being free.

I also understand that words like absolutism or absolute power imply the object has ultimate  freedom to rule even though its subjects are restrained, but then, say, if we describe the "law of conservation of energy" as an *absolute* principle of physics, then there is neither *freedom* for interpretation nor an "absolute ruler" who possess the "freedom" to legislate. (After all, it is commonly regarded as the universal truth and none "arbitrarily made up" the law.)

Then where does the freedom in "absolute" go, since there is no recipient to the freedom and everyone else is subject to the restriction? I am still confused about whether ***absolute*** conveys freedom or its opposite.

Comment: Your logic fails at “away from being loose”—the prefix _ab-_ does mean ‘away’, but it is “loosened away”, rather than “away from being loosened”, just like _abstaining_ is “holding off/away”, not “away from holding”.

Comment: And I suspect that the second part is as in "solution" -- the more accurate translation thus becoming "undiluted".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OED etymology says:

> from Latin *absolūt-um* loosened, free, separate, acquitted, completed, etc; past participle of *absolv-ere*: see *absolve*. The senses were largely taken direct from Latin, in which the development of meaning had already taken place, so that they do not form a historical series in Eng. 
>   Originally a participle -- absolved, disengaged: then an adjective -- disengaged or free from imperfection or qualification; from interference, connexion, relation, comparison, dependence; from condition, conditional forms of knowledge or thought.

The critical point is that "freedom" simply means 'separated'; that's the original source of the PIE root, which shows up also in the paradigm [Greek verb ***λύω***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Greek_grammar_(tables)#Formation_of_the_tenses).

In other words, you **can't** tell, from the Latin affixes, what it means in English.
Because it was borrowed as a unit, with the affixes and the meanings already attached to it
by **Latin** speakers. The affixes are no longer productive in English, though they can be helpful.

Comment: I think it might improve the answer (since I had to spend a second or two puzzling it out) to change "pa pple" to "[past participle]"?

Comment: But now you know, right?

Comment: Now I _believe I have interpreted your intent correctly_; which is only approximately the same :-)

Comment: A pa pple a day gives the critics their say.

Answer (score 5):

Etymonline.com refers in its entry for *absolute* to the word *absolve*, which in turn points to the entry for [*solve*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=solve&allowed_in_frame=0):

> from PIE *se-lu-, from reflexive pronoun *s(w)e- (see *idiom*) + root *leu- "to loosen, divide, cut apart" (see *lose*)

Thus, the sense in *absolute* is "cut away", in the sense of "cut away from any restrictions".

When you say that something is an *absolute* principle of physics, you are saying that it is unrestricted, not bound by consideration of something else, hence "free of/cut away from restriction".

Comment: Is it ok to omit "abs-" from absolve and examine solve? (This is exactly what the dictionary did, but I am a bit worried about believing that it is just what it is without any annotation on the matter. I mean, absolve and solve are obviously very similar, and yet the prefix "abs-" in absolve does not give it a different meaning from solve.) Btw, I love your interpretation of the absolute principle. In a sense, freedom is also conserved because something or someone is always free.

Comment: Also, thank you for the website. It will help me a lot with my studying.

Comment: Exactly. Once we examine _solve_, we can see "to cut apart, divide"; and then we can add _abs-_ meaning "away", and get "cut away".

Comment: (Which means essentially the same thing as "divide"; but that's because - as John Lawler states in his answer - the words were borrowed independently, as units, and not borrowed as root and affix which were later reconnected.)